# Filtering a NSDictionary progressively as one types by value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Currently, I am working with a large `NSDictionary` called `listOfAllWords` that contains a word, and a corresponding score as such:

```
WORD  : SCORE
-------------
hello : 100
have  : 90
help  : 80
held  : 70
hot   : 60
hemp  : 50
...
```

My goal is, as a user is typing, provide up to 3 suggestions from the list as ranked based on their **score**.

For example, if the user has only typed "**h**", the 3 recommendations would be "hello", "have" and help", in that order. However, if the user has typed "**hel**" already, then the recommendations would be "hello", "help" and "held".

Based on the similar paradigm of filtering UITableViews, the way to filter would be to do something like this:

```
    for (word* food in [listOfAllWords allKeys]){
        NSRange nameRange = [word rangeOfString:userInput options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound
        {
            [filteredData addObject:word];
        }
    }
```

However, the issue I am running into is how to incorporate the filter to include the **score** component as well, so that it would include recommendations ranked by their scores. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest that you create an object with `word` and `score` properties.  Add instances of these objects to your `filteredData` array and then you can sort the array by `score` descending & take the first 3 elements

Comment: This is better solved using a radix tree.  (But of course that takes work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward approach might be something like this:

```
NSArray* matchingWords = [listOfAllWords.allKeys filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", userInput];
NSArray* sortedMatches = [matchingWords sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult (NSString* word1, NSString* word2) {
    // Look up the score of each word and compare them. I put word2's score on the left to get descending (highest first) result.
    return [listOfAllWords[word2] compare:listOfAllWords[word1]];
}];
// Limit to 3 matches
if (sortedMatches.count > 3)
    sortedMatches = [sortedMatches subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
```

It is definitely possible to improve on the speed of this, but don't bother unless and until you've measured a real performance problem.

Comment: Thanks! This works great, with almost no performance hit. My only follow up is, how do I improve the `NSPredicate` so that rather than finding a partially entered string in any part of the `matchingWords`, it would only find it in the beginning of `matchWords`. For example, if I typed only "he", the result should begin with "he-" only (and not have suggestions like "the") Thanks!

Comment: Replace `CONTAINS` with `BEGINSWITH`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a second dictionary with keys and values swapped like described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19387825/364015

Then do a sort on the keys, and look up the values in their sorted order to create an ordered set of the strings.